# asp.net localization question

Tags: asp.net, localization, culture

I have two resource files:
`Resource1.resx` and `Resource1.es-mx.resx`
The default system culture is `en-US`.

1. `<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>` --> still get English version (setting language in the browser doesn't help).
2. Rename `Resource1.es-mx.resx` to `Resource1.es.resx` --> works, Spanish.
3. `<%@ Page UICulture="auto" Culture="auto" %>`, set Spanish in the browser, resource `Resource1.es-mx.resx` --> Spanish.

Could you explain to me what happens in the first case? Why English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why English? There are no Spanish country-neutral resources and you ask specifically for them. So it falls back to neutral resources (which happens to be English in your case).

You should do that the other way round: name resources file `Resource1.es.resx` and ask for specific UICulture: `UICulture="es-MX"` if you have to. In such case, if country-specific resources are not found, it will fall back to Spanish country-neutral resources (es).
I am not aware of your use case, but hard-coding cultures is not really good idea... You really should think about using *auto* here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `UICulture="es-mx"`? I believe, but I'm not 100% sure, that if the second part of the locale is specified on the resource file, it is only used where both parts are specified.